# Implementation of A-Frame Extras FBX loader

Tags: aframe

Seeking an example of FBX loading within A-frame. Aframe Extras docs say that the FBX loader is experimental and only ASCII format is supported. Now I've exported the correct format yet I cannot view the file in my scene. Any ideas?

`<a-entity fbx-model="src: url(https://mannymeadows.github.io/Noosa/models/FBX-DEMO.fbx);" material="color: red" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Demo - http://codepen.io/MannyMeadows/pen/mmaLWv

Comment: One side note, the `material` component doesn't work with custom models (except maybe OBJ). But that's not the issue here.

Comment: The bug is in a-frame extras. The THREE.FBXLoader is loading the model properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `fbx-model` component correctly. In the JS console you'll see an error thrown from: `THREE.FBXLoader.parseMesh`:

```
aframe-extras.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1926113552' in undefined
  at e.exports.THREE.FBXLoader.parseMesh (aframe-extras.min.js:1)
  at e.exports.THREE.FBXLoader.parseMeshes (aframe-extras.min.js:1)
  at e.exports.THREE.FBXLoader.parse (aframe-extras.min.js:1)
  at aframe-extras.min.js:1
  at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:29211)
```

To verify that your model is good, try opening it in [FBX Review](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/fbx-review).

If that works, THREE.FBXLoader just can't read the file for some reason. It's not uncommon unfortunately: FBX is a complex format, and isn't easy to support on the web. You can file a bug on [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), but may ultimately want to convert to another format like OBJ or glTF.